# How to determine the percentage of selection in a list

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a list that I display to a user and allow the user to make selections from. I would like to know if the selections made by the user is equal to or greater than 75% (or 3/4) of items in the list. Can someone point me in the right direction.

I have tried the following:

```
if(selectedItems >= ((3/4) * arraySize)){
    Log.d("REM", "Got it");
} else {
    Log.d("REM", "Not there yet");
}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: How are you managing the selected items? Also in a list? Assuming you have lists `items` and `selectedItems` you can compare `selectedItems.size() >= 0.75*items.size()`.

Comment: @user1983983 No, the selected items are not in a list, it's a count of items selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because 3/4 will return 0 in Java I think.

```
selectedItems >= (0.75 * arraySize)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this
 Just converted into float

```
if(selectedItems >= (((float)3/4) * arraySize)){
log.d("REM", "Got it");
}else{
log.d("REM", "Not there yet");
}
```